# Training CNN Model and accuracy stays at 1

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

I've been trying to train this CNN Model, It's a Tensorflow tutorial and I just changed the dataset ( I used fruit 360 dataset) without altering the core of the code. When it finishes training the accuracy stays constant at 0.8565 it doesn't change and when I try and test some images it almost always wrong.
What am I doing wrong?

[Code output after executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DatCp.jpg)

Here's the code I used

```
[enter image description here][1]import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf
import tarfile

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from tensorflow import keras

import pathlib

dataset_url = "https://file.io/z5JM3sYAWXv4"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=dataset_url,
                                   fname='tomatos',
                                   untar=True,
                                   extract=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)



print(data_dir)



file_count = sum(len(files) for _, _, files in os.walk(r'tomatos'))
print(file_count)

batch_size = 32
img_height = 180
img_width = 180

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
num_classes = len(class_names)

model = Sequential([
  layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

epochs=2
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)

data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
  [
    layers.RandomFlip("horizontal",
                      input_shape=(img_height,
                                  img_width,
                                  3)),
    layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
    layers.RandomZoom(0.1),
  ]
)
model = Sequential([
  data_augmentation,
  layers.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

epochs = 4
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)

sunflower_url = "https://puffycarrot.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Green-tomatoes.jpg"
sunflower_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('tomato2', origin=sunflower_url)

img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(
    sunflower_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
)
img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

print(
    "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
    .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
)
```

Comment: I can't test your code because https://file.io/z5JM3sYAWXv4 is not a tar or zip archive

Comment: @elbe oh sorry here's the updated link https://www.upload.ee/download/13972706/67f334b20e121ab9f30f/tomatos.zip

Comment: I ran your code and get 100% accuracy for train and validation sets on the last epoch for both models, with and without data augmentation. Also the image _Green-tomatoes.jpg_ _most likely belongs to Tomato not Ripened with a 100.00 percent confidence_ which seems correct.

Comment: @elbe where did you test the code? I tested it on google colab and it seems it's working just fine but when I test it on Pycharm it's faulty and the result was that it's ripe although it's not. Where could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

@Yaman Tarawneh, I tried replicating your above mentioned code in `Google colab` (using TF 2.8) and in `Pycharm` (using TF 2.7) and did not find the error.

Please check the output image for Pycharm :[image]

and got the same output in `Google colab` :

```
Total params: 3,988,898
Trainable params: 3,988,898
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/4

    78/78 [==============================] - 8s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0309 - accuracy: 0.9835 - val_loss: 5.6374e-07 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
    Epoch 2/4
    78/78 [==============================] - 2s 25ms/step - loss: 5.7533e-07 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 2.7360e-07 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
    Epoch 3/4
    78/78 [==============================] - 2s 25ms/step - loss: 3.0400e-07 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.3978e-07 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
    Epoch 4/4
    78/78 [==============================] - 2s 25ms/step - loss: 1.7403e-07 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 7.2102e-08 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

This image most likely belongs to Tomato not Ripened with a 100.00 percent confidence.
```

For further analysis if the issue still persists, Please let us know which `Python` and `Tensorflow version` are you using.